# i18n: error message localization for particular model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization

I can localize an error message for each validation, but how can I create an error for particular model.

Ordinary locale looks like this:

```
en:
  mongoid:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "It is already taken"
```

But I want to change message for `user` model:

```
en:
  mongoid:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "It is already taken"
        user:
          taken: "It is already taken. %{link_to 'Remember password', reset_password_path'}"
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
en:
  mongoid:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "It is already taken"
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            login:
              taken: "It is already taken. %{link}"
```

**Reference:**

[ActiveRecord code comments](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml#L15)

**PS:**
The localization string should use interpolation variable for dynamic substitution.

E.g:
Add an error on the `login` field of  `user` object:

```
user.errors.add(:login, :taken, :link => "foo")
```

Comment: Can you explain how do you know that? How can I understand path to whatever I need in localizations? PS: as link I just use brutal raw HTML

Comment: It is mentioned in the ActiveRecord code comments. I assumed mangoid might follow the same convention.

Comment: I tried this for adding a link to my password reset form but keep getting this error: `missing interpolation argument in "is not valid. Click %{link} to re-send you password. confirmation" ({:model=>"User", :attribute=>"Password token", :value=>nil} given)`. Has anything changed in Rails 3.1?