# String interpolation in I18n for active record validation errors

Tags: rails-i18n

I have a non-user-friendly validation error message that I want to override:

```
Cannot delete record because dependent [unfriendly model names] exist
```

where the association is

```
has_many :unfriendly_model_names, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

I want it to be

```
Cannot delete record because dependent [nice readable model names] exist
```

I expect I could use I18n, but how and at what point do I pass a friendlier string in to the `record` interpolation?

```
en-GB:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        restrict_dependent_destroy:
          has_many: "Cannot delete record because dependent %{record} exist"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i18n: error message localization for particular model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125127/i18n-error-message-localization-for-particular-model)

Answer (score 0):

You have to localize the association attribute. So, if you are trying to destroy a `user` with many `posts` restricted with error:

```yaml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        posts: "nice readable model names"
```

The reason is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb#L20